Expressing a combination as sums of three terms or more, analogous to Pascal's identity
Are there any ways to express binomial coefficients as the sum of three or more terms, similar to how Pascal's Identity breaks a combination into the sum of two terms by relating two adjacent binomial coefficients.
If such an identity exists, what is it? If not, are there any alternative methods or approaches to express combinations as sums of three terms or more(each term not necessarily a combination)?
I appreciate any insights or references to relevant literature on this topic. Thank you!

Well, you could break the two terms in Pascal's identity further by Pascal's identity.

@ploosu2 yes I had considered that obviously but isn't there any way other than it?

Splitting as a sum of $n$ terms is natural for $n$-nomial coefficients (coefficients of the expansion of $(x_1+x_2+\dots +x_n)^m$) .  For binomials the "natural" splitting is as a sum of $2$ terms.

@user3257842 thanks! That's really helpful

By recursive application of the binomial identity $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k} + \binom{n-1}{k-1}$ you get  $\binom{n}{k} = \sum_{p=0}^{m} \binom{n-m}{k-p}\binom{m}{p}$

You have the following quadratic equation for the binomial coefficient:
$\binom{k}{i}= \binom{k}{i}^2 + 2 \sum_{j=1}^{i}{(-1)^j  \binom{k}{i-j} \binom{k}{i+j}}
$
There are some related sequences in the OEIS like for example:
A108958
